# Why the imported war file does not work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am working with my classmates on a assignment that makes a dynamic web project, previously he has sent me a version as war file and i have imported the file into my eclipse and it worked fine, later he has worked on it a little bit an sent me that newer version of the project and I have done the same thing imported as a new war file into my eclipse, but this time it does not work at all when I run the project an a tomcat server, it says the resource not found.

Does anyone know the reasons?

Comment: What do you mean by "WAR" in Eclipse. Usually, you put the WAR file in webapps folder under your Tomcat installation directory and start the server.

Comment: web archive file, it is generated when you right click on the web project folder and click on export and you can choose the format of the exporting file you can choose the WAR file

Comment: It's probably having trouble starting, check the Tomcat logs.

Comment: @RayStojonic, you are right the tomcat logs show a ClassNotFoundException, what does that mean

Comment: and says this as well: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener

Comment: It means [jaxws-rt.jar](https://jax-ws.java.net/) is missing.

Comment: Did you check if class-not-found is present in your war or runtime class-path libraries?

Comment: @RayStojonic - I have downloaded the jaxws-ir.jar but how do I import into project?

Comment: Does the war work for your classmate? What you need to find out is why it isn't in there in the first place. What is being used to build the project?

Comment: he says it works, and i have downloaded the .jar pasted into tomcat lib , it gave me java.util.concurrent.executionexception

Comment: We'll need the full trace

Answer (score 0):

While importing war do this 2 steps:

1. Do not choose default Apache Target runtime or it will throw an error
2. Do not check Web libraries (add them manually after import if they are not added to the path)